# git clone and checkout in a single command

Tags: git, clone, commit, git-checkout

The following is the command I use to checkout a specific commit.

```
git clone git://repo.git/repo123
git checkout <commitID>
```

I want to do the above in one step - using a git clone command only.

The reason why I want to do this is, repo123 is very huge. So checking out the commit I want will save me a lot of time.

I am aware of `--depth` option. But in this case, it is of no use. Can anyone tell me how to do it?

Comment: What is the problem of `--depth`?

Answer (score 91):

```
git clone u://r/l --branch x
```

still clones everything but sets the local HEAD to that branch so it's the one checked out.

[Source](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone#Documentation/git-clone.txt---branchltnamegt):

> **--branch <name>** 
>
>   **-b <name>** 
>
>   Instead of pointing the newly created HEAD to the branch pointed to by the cloned repository’s HEAD, point to `<name>` branch instead. In a non-bare repository, this is the branch that will be checked out. `--branch` can also take tags and detaches the HEAD at that commit in the resulting repository.

Comment: That is what I have been wanting to implement .. that is very helpful thanks,

Answer (score 6):

Is your problem the *checkout* being to large or the *repository* itself?
As `git clone`, well, clones a repository you usually get the whole repository in its full size. (unless you are doing a shallow clone as you already suggested.)

If it's really about the checkout of the wrong branch `git help clone` says:

```
   --no-checkout, -n
       No checkout of HEAD is performed after the clone is complete.
```

After cloning with `-n` you can manually check out

Answer (score 3):

I was running into a same situation and it worked well with the Git Clone Command with `--depth`. And specify the branch-name/commit/Tag-Name at the end of the command with `-b` parameter.

Syntax:

```
git clone --depth 1 github.com:ORG-NAME/Repo.git -b <Branch-Name/Commit-Number/TAG>
```

Comment: Does this really work for a commit SHA1? I've tried it with git 2.5.0 and although it accepts branch names and tags, it doesn't work with commits.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question, but judging by dates of answers and comments it's still relevant, so I figured I'd add my few cents.

If the commit you want to clone is a tip of the branch or a tag, you can - as mentioned in other answers - do:

```
git clone --depth 1 --branch <branch/tag name> <repository URL>
```

If, however, you want to clone the commit by its SHA (as indicated in the question), you need to run several commands:

```
mkdir -p <local repository directory>
cd <local repository directory>
git init
git remote add origin <repository URL>
git fetch --depth 1 origin <commit SHA>
git checkout FETCH_HEAD
```

If you have to do it often, you could make it into a function/cmdlet.

For example in Bash:

```
git_clone_commit() {
    mkdir -p "$1"
    pushd "$1"
    git init
    git remote add origin "$3"
    git fetch --depth 1 origin "$2"
    git checkout FETCH_HEAD
    git submodule update --init --recursive
    popd
}
```

and then

```
git_clone_commit <local repository directory> <commit SHA> <repository URL>
```

Comment: Just to be clear: Your second code snippet / the Bash function works for both commit SHAs and branches/tags, correct? After all, `git fetch` supports both.

Comment: I haven't tested it, but it should. After all 3 are valid references to a commit.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just want to be able to "walk away" and return when both steps have completed.  I use this line for two long-running commands on a single line -- and I like to "time" the overall action.

The trick is the semi-colon between each command.

```
$ time (git clone git://repo.git/repo123 ; git checkout <commitID>)
```